# Fastest way to find a number in an unknown range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for the horrible title - I'm new to python and I'm not sure how to describe my question. So the question asks:

> x plus 100 is a perfect square number, plus another 168 is also a perfect square number. Find x.

And here's my answer:

```
from math import sqrt
for x in range(-100,10000):
    a=int(sqrt(x+100))
    b=int(sqrt(x+100+168))
    if (a*a!=x+100) or (b*b!=x+100+168):
        continue
    else:
        print(x)
```

The problem is, I don't *actually* know the range. I only know that the number can't be smaller than -100, but the 10000 is only a random large number that I put in there. Is there a way for me to figure out a smaller range first? Or a way that I could make this faster?

Comment: The upper limit of the range is going to have absolutely no effect on how long it takes to find the first solution.  To speed up the process, consider iterating over square numbers, rather than all numbers - there's much fewer of them!  Add each square number `S` to a set, see if `S-168` was already in the set.  If so, display `S-268` as a solution.

Comment: Why check every number starting at 1 to potentially infinity? Stand the problem on it head: go through each perfect square larger than 100, add 168 and see if that number is a perfect square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want every solution in the range, this is a faster solution

```
for x in range(-100,10000):
    if ((x+100)**.5).is_integer():       
        if ((x+268)**.5).is_integer():
            print(x)
```

If only the first solution is required, you can add a `break` after the `print` statement.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easily ascertainable upper bound to your problem: after a couple of numbers, the difference between perfect squares is much larger than 168. (Take a look at 100^2 and 101^2. The results are perfect squares about 200 apart. With this your number will be no larger than 10,000).

If you would like to speed up your problem, rather than checking if a number is square, you can check if by squaring numbers you can achieve a solution.

```
for x in range(0,100):
    y=x
    while y**2 - x**2 < 169 and y < 100:
        y+=1
        if y**2 - x**2 == 168:
            print("Your number is: " + str(x**2 - 100))
```

Edit: code was broken, fixed. Running this gives you -99 (-99 + 100 is 1, is a perfect square, 1 + 168 is 169, which is 13^2), 21, 261, and 1581

Comment: I don't understand why ```y**2 - x**2 == 168``` works. Could you elaborate on that please? Shouldn't the condition be that both (x+100) and (x+268) are perfect squares?

Comment: Rather than starting at -100 and going up to 10,000 and checking which numbers are square roots, this starts at 0 and goes up to 100 and squares each number, guaranteeing that the result is a perfect square. Not only is squaring faster than square root, it also has a much smaller range of numbers.

Therefore, x and y aren't the perfect squares themselves, instead, they are the *square roots* of the perfect squares and need to be squared to get the actual number, which is also why when it prints out, it prints x^2 and subtracts a 100 because the number says that the solution + 100 is square.

Answer (score 1):

Since the prompt assumes only one correct value of `x`, then there is no need to use a `for` loop, as we can just loop indefinitely using a `while` and no upper bound is known.

To check if the result of an operation is a whole number, we can check if the float and integer representation of the number are equal, i.e. `int(num) == num`.

```py
>>> i = 1
>>> while True:
        a, b = (i+100)**0.5, (i+268)**0.5
        if int(a) == a and int(b) == b:
            break
        i += 1

        
>>> i
21
```

And if we check the quality of the result obtained, both results are whole numbers:

```py
>>> (i+100)**0.5
11.0
>>> (i+268)**0.5
17.0
```

Comment: Actually, the second condition should be that ```(i+268)**0.5```, as mentioned in the question: "plus another 168".

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi Thank you for pointing that out.